# Entailment of a negative case

Tags: logic

The lecture notes for my logic course say that the statement

> If $\Gamma\models\neg\phi[\tau]$ for some ground term $\tau$, then
>   $\Gamma\not\models\forall x.\phi[x]$

is false. But I don't see why this is the case.

Why is't the above statement true?

Comment: For context, it appears that the [problem set](http://logic.stanford.edu/classes/csxyz/problems/problems2.html) is available (look at problem 3.g), and in a form with answers [here](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/exercises/exercise_06_12_01.html) (problem c).

Comment: The question arises from the lecture notes to the [Coursera version](https://www.coursera.org/course/intrologic) of the same course, *not* from a problem set in that course. However, if the Stanford version of the course is still using the linked problem set, this question should probably be deleted.

Comment: It's good to see logic courses on Coursera!  The problem set I linked to says ©1995–2007, but I have no idea whether they're still using it or not.  I only linked because the course material there, particularly [Chapter 6](http://logic.stanford.edu/classes/cs157/2009/notes/chap06.html) covers this in some detail, and I thought other readers might be interested.  Since a page on the same site includes the answers to those exercises, I doubt there's any problem with them being discussed here.

Comment: Good, I hope the question can stay. I've flagged it anyway so the moderators can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $\Gamma$ required to be consistent?

If not then an inconsistent $\Gamma$ would have the property that $\Gamma\models\psi$ for any proposition, in particular the two from your statement.

Comment: The statement is prefaced with "Let $\Gamma$ be a set of Relational Logic sentences..."

Comment: Then there is no requirement that $\Gamma$ is consistent.

Comment: So, unless $\Gamma$ is required to be consistent, statements of the form *If $\Gamma\models\phi$ then $\Gamma\not\models\psi$* are *never* true, even when $\phi\iff\neg\psi$?

Comment: Exactly. Inconsistent sets of sentences entail everything.